# Fetch a component by its tcm id using the core services

Tags: tridion

I need to fetch a component based on its tcm id using the core services. Please help me which function of core service I can use along with some sample code if possible as well.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Tridion has its own StackExchange: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/. Allthough this particular question might not be in there, there's loads of other useful questions regarding the Coreservice in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the section in the documentation, which you can find [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-5FF3DFE0-8F12-4B71-B8D9-6AE9790F43B4&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-5FF3DFE0-8F12-4B71-B8D9-6AE9790F43B4.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-5FF3DFE0-8F12-4B71-B8D9-6AE9790F43B4)

A basic sample (out of my head, untested ;) ):

```
ComponentData component = (ComponentData)client.Read(yourComponentId, new ReadOptions());
string title = component.Title;
XElement content = XElement.Parse(component.Content);
```

The `Read` method will get you an `IdentifiableObjectData` object, which you can cast to the needed type if you're sure about what you're supposed to be getting back. 
The `ReadOptions` object will instruct the CoreService how to load the item, for instance, with all Keyword URI's loaded as well using `LoadFlags.KeywordXlinks`